# Programatically load a webpage in C# and click an agreement button to access webpage contents

Tags: c#, post, webclient, webrequest, forms, http-post

Using C#, I am attempting to grab/scrape the data from the content of a web page with a couple parameters:

https://www.frbservices.org/EPaymentsDirectory/FedACHdir.txt?updatedSince=10%2F01%2F2015&downloadButton=

I am able to use the WebClient and WebRequests objects to make the request and receive a response, but the initial time the page is hit, it is asking to click an "Agree" button.  It it possible to hit this web page, mimic the button click if it exists, and get to the page (secondary response with the .txt content) simply using C# code?

I'm open to other ideas as well if anyone has any.

Thank you.

Comment: [This](https://www.frbservices.org/EPaymentsDirectory/agreement.html) is the agreement page they redirect you to. Just check if the URL matches.

Comment: I think it's probably worth considering if the button you're referring to is asking you to agree not to do what you're trying to do - from a quick glance at the license agreement it would appear to be. Just thought I'd mention it anyway!

Comment: "Just check if the URL matches."  I'm trying to put this together:  So use the WebClient to post to the inital URL, then what exactly do I check?  Does the response hold the Redirect URL?  If it does, and it matches, then how to I submit that particular form or click the "Agree" button?

Comment: I assume you are doing this so a user can skip that page. I really recommend against it, if it is not a site you own. As an end user, they should explicitly agree to any TOS, even if they don't read it

Answer (score 1):

```
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new Dictionary<string, string> { { "agreementValue", "Agree" } });
                var agreementPost = await client.PostAsync("https://www.frbservices.org/EPaymentsDirectory/submitAgreement", content);
                var dataString = await (await client.GetAsync("https://www.frbservices.org/EPaymentsDirectory/FedACHdir.txt")).Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Web browser control concept to click

webBrowser.Navigate("http://www.google.com");
webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("id").InvokeMember("click");

Answer (score 0):

SHDocVw.InternetExplorer IE = new SHDocVw.InternetExplorer();
            IE.Navigate("https://www.frbservices.org/EPaymentsDirectory/agreement.html");

```
        IE.Visible = true;

            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
```

IE.Document.getElementById["agree_terms_use"].click();

Comment: This does not answer the actual question. If it does, how is it so?